# Different size images in a carousel to display in vertical align middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I created a simple carousel with outer DIV which has width and height set to 600 X 800 and position set at "position:relative" and the images inside this DIV to be "position:absolute" with top and left to be zero. I have kept a "left/right" button as well, so that whenever I click left/right button the images would move left/right accordingly by using JQuery. It all works fine including responsive.
But I have a problem when I have different sizes of images, I want to display it in horizontal and vertical center ("vertical-align:middle"). I tried different ways in CSS but seems no luck. I know I can do it using JavaScript, but wondering if anybody can help me using CSS only please, much appreciated... I want to avoid JavaScript if possible.
Please note that this carousel is showing one image at a time. This is how I have designed/programmed.

This is my present code :

```
<div style="position:relative;">
   
    // image style is set to position:absolute;left:0;top:0
    //  _______________________________________
    //  |           |          |               |
    //  |           |          |_______________|
    //  |           |          |               
    //  |___________|          | 
    //              |__________|
    //

</div>
```

I want it to be like this :

```
<div>
   
    //              ___________
    //  ____________|          |
    //  |           |          |_______________
    //  |           |          |               |
    //  |           |          |_______________|
    //  |___________|          | 
    //              |__________|

</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox on your container div.

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bendelszl, but when clicking the next button, the next image is flickering on the right side of the DIV. Its less than a second, but doesn't look good though. Thanks again.

Comment: I can suggest you can add transition to make it smooth, if not added yet. The flickering may be because of the change in left or translate value used by you.